# Constant concentration for chi square variables

Tags: probability, statistics, chi-squared, concentration-of-measure

I would like to have a certain concentration inequality for chi square variables with $k$ degrees of freedom. As referenced in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/what-are-the-sharpest-known-tail-bounds-for-chi-k2-distributed-variables, Laurant and Massart give as a corollary that
$$
\Pr\left(\left\lvert X-\mathbb E(X)\right\rvert\geq 2\sqrt{kx}+2x\right)\leq 2\exp(-x).
$$
However, I only care about the case where the right hand side is constant, say $1/10$ (so $x\approx 3$), and I would like a weaker dependence on $k$, say $k^{1/4}$ instead of $k^{1/2}$. I only care about the asymptotic order of $k$, so anything $O(k^{1/2-\varepsilon})$ would be great. Could anyone suggest any results/approaches, or could it be impossible? Thank you!

Comment: This discussion began on stats.stackexchange with a slightly different version of Laurant and Massart's work than you quote here. Maybe it should continue there. // Perhaps you could start by saying you are interested in $x \approx 2.3.$ And whether you really care about the left tail.

Comment: I misquoted their theorem and I have fixed it, thank you! I really do care about the left tail as well, but I only care about the order of $k$ and not so much the lower order terms and that is why I joined the two inequalities into one. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: Well, taking $x \sim 1/\sqrt{k}$ gives you a  $k^{1/4}$ dependence on $k$. I don't think your can do this for $x$ chosen irrespectively of $k$. In particular, $x$ would have to be very small...